# Retrieving data by id from the card listed with Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

I post an ad in my app.
I pull the ads as a list from the firebase and list them with the recycler adapter. Using ViewModel.
In each ad, there is the ID of the person who published the ad.
My problem;
I want to show the information about the advertiser in the card, but I could not find how to extract the data with the advertiser's ID in the adapter and connect it to each card. How should I go about this?
I thought about transferring all users along with my ad list to the adapter and finding them from there, but it doesn't seem to be the right method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.
I access my repository in Adapter as follows;

```
    val repo: FirebaseRepoInterFace

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface RepoEntryPoint {
        fun getRepo(): FirebaseRepoInterFace
    }

    init {
        val repoEntryPoint =
            EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(context, RepoEntryPoint::class.java)
        repo = repoEntryPoint.getRepo()
    }
```

Then, with the method in my repository, I bring the different users with their ids for each card.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        post.userId?.let { id ->
            repo.getUserDataByDocumentId(id).addOnSuccessListener {
                holder.binding.user = it.toObject(UserModel::class.java)
            }
        }
}
```